# How to add links between the nodes when displaying

Tags: java

I am trying to display my tree using the above display function.
It works well but , it just want help on how I can add links between my nodes when I am displaying so it can show the tree structure.

Currently my display function will give the following output

[image]

But I would want it to display something like the image below with links connecting nodes

[image]

Here's the code that currently prints the tree

```
public void display(Node root) // display search tree
    {
        Stack<Node> tStack = new Stack<Node>();
        tStack.push(root);
        int numOfBlanks = 32;
        boolean isRowEmpty = false;
        System.out.println("\n");

        while (isRowEmpty == false) 
        {
            Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();

            isRowEmpty = true;

            for (int x = 0; x < numOfBlanks; x++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            while (tStack.isEmpty() == false) 
            {
                Node n = (Node)tStack.pop();

                if (n != null)
                {
                    System.out.print(n.value);
                    stack.push(n.left);
                    stack.push(n.right);

                    if (n.left != null || n.right != null)
                    {
                        isRowEmpty = false;
                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                     System.out.print("--");
                     stack.push(null);
                     stack.push(null);
                 }

                for (int y = 0; y < numOfBlanks*2-2; y++)
                {
                     System.out.print(" ");
                }

             }
            System.out.println("\n");

            numOfBlanks /= 2;
            while (stack.isEmpty() == false)
            {
                tStack.push(stack.pop());
            }


        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
```

Comment: You mean on the console? I have my doubt there's a reliable way to do that without changing, e.g., the height of each level of the tree. If you're ok having different heights, you could do something with the `/` and `\ ` characters.

Comment: Would it be ok to use `|` and `-----` instead of diagonals?

Comment: Yes it would be fine, as long it would give me a more or less display like i am looking for